# Converting React + Material UI + Firebase template code over to hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently converting the React + Material UI + Firebase template code found on the Material UI doc's page. However, I am currently having trouble connecting a signup button click (now using hooks) which should open a model for a user. To make things simple, I have included the codesandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-react-hooks-7cm6j). As you can see though, nothing renders when the button is clicked.

Comment: There are several problems here. Your openDialog function is just returning a function, rather than invoking one. And even when the state is changed properly, the prop is not being passed down to the Dialog component to actually open it.

Comment: No sure how to fix the first portion, but I believe I am properly passing it down into SignUpDialog now

Comment: Did you figure this out?